# Ionic gradle download error

Tags: android, gradle, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

When i try to run "ionic run android", the screen shows its downloading gradle distribution 2.13-all. All that happens is dots appear on the screen and it stays like that.

I have already tried downloading the gradle zip and placing the zip in the gradle/wrapper folder but what happens is when I run "ionic run android" again, the folder disappears and it starts again with downloading gradle.

I also tried updating the build sdk tools in the android manager but that didnt work either.

Comment: Downloading might take a while. How long do you wait?

Comment: about an hour now, that's hwy i think it lags

Comment: I do not know ionic, but is there any option for working offline in your IDE? Can you open the url to the gradle distribution with your browser?

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the *distributionUrl* on the GradleBuilder.js file?("yourApp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\builders\GradleBuilder.js")

If not, find this:

`var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=http\\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';`

and change it to your zip location:

`var distributionUrl = 'distributionUrl=../gradle-2.2.1-all.zip';`

Comment: that was it but now I am getting Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

Comment: I'm not sure if the following solutions will help you resolve that problem, but you could try to run `cordova platform update android` or check if your $JAVA_HOME is set (if not, set it).